# Distribution of heat on a ring (fourier series)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, heat-equation

I know that the general solution to temperature distribution on a ring of circumference length 1 is given by the Fourier series

$$T(x,t) = \sum_{n= - \infty}^{n=\infty} c_n(0) e^{-2 \pi^2 n^2 t} e^{2 \pi i n x}$$

where

$$c_n(0) = \int_0^1 T(x,0) e^{-2 \pi i n x} dx$$

If I start with a temperature distribution

$$T(x,0) = cos(2 \pi x) + 1$$

I calculate $c_{n \ne 0}(0) = 0$ and $c_{n=0}(0)=1$.

Consequently

$$T(x,t) = 1$$

which contradicts the original assumption that $T(x,0) = cos(2 \pi x)+1$.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Redo your calculation of $c_1(0),$ it is wrong. To quickly see why, note that $e^{i(2\pi x)} = \cos(2\pi x) + i \sin(2\pi x),$ and so $\int \cos (2\pi x) e^{i(2\pi 
x)}$ must have a nonzero real part.

Comment: You're right. Thank you! I was trying to obtain a general solution for "n", leading to a 1/0 when n=1. So clearly my generalization for n was not valid for n=1. I need to calculate the n=1 case explicitly, as you pointed out.